# Bremsstrahlung x-ray appears due to energy conservation?

Tags: electric-fields, photons, energy-conservation, x-rays

Consider an electron that is launched towards an atomic nucleus. As the electron gets closer to the nucleus, the electric potential energy between these particles changes, it decreases. According to energy conservation what follows is an increase of energy outside of this electron-nucleus system. Is it now correct to say that the emitted bremsstrahlung x-rays provide this increase in energy?

Comment: Energy conservation does not imply increase of energy outside the electron-nucleus system. The lost potential energy appears mostly as increased kinetic energy of the electron and nucleus, only small part goes to increasing the EM energy due to radiation.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/xrayc.html  second paragraph